# Usage of q-card-actions

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

In https://quasar.dev/vue-components/card#with-actions, I simply change `q-card-actions` to `q-card-section`, I saw some padding changes. Wrapping buttons in `q-card-actions`, but not `q-card-section`  - is it only for the padding change or there are other purposes?